# filter records from a collection having max value of a particular column using aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to fetch "all the documents" having highest value for specific field and than group by another field.

Consider below data:

```
_id:1, type:debug, status:Pass, build:13,  params:abc,  time:1
_id:2, type:debug, status:Pass, build:10,  params:abc,  time:2
_id:3, type:test,  status:Pass, build:13,  params:xyz,  time:3
_id:4, type:debug, status:Pass, build:12,  params:abc,  time:4
_id:5, type:debug, status:Pass, build:13,  params:xyz,  time:5
_id:6, type:debug, status:NA,   build:13,  params:abc,  time:6
_id:7, type:debug, status:Pass, build:13,  params:abc,  time:6
_id:8, type:test,  status:Fail, build:13,  params:xyz,  time:6
_id:9, type:debug, status:NA,   build:13,  params:pqr,  time:6
```

I want 
- first filter data with status Pass or Fail
- then filter from the step1 data with max build value(which is 13 here)
- then group by params with average of time

Expected Output:

```
params:abc  time:3.5
params:xyz  time:4.67
```

Comment: Could you paste expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can find the max id, lookup max id in the same collection filtering matching max id,and do group aggregation to get the desired results on the matched documents

pipeline

```
db.e2e.aggregate(
    [
        {$group   : {_id : null, maxBuild : {$max : "$build"}}},
        {$lookup  : {from : "e2e", localField : "maxBuild", foreignField : "build", as : "builds"}},
        {$unwind  : "$builds"},
        {$group   : {_id : {build : "$builds.build", params : "$builds.params"}, time : {$avg : "$builds.time"}}},
        {$project : {_id : 0, build : "$_id.build", params : "$_id.params", time : "$time"}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

result

```
{ "build" : 13, "params" : "xyz", "time" : 4 }
{ "build" : 13, "params" : "abc", "time" : 3.5 }
>
```

**EDIT**

you need to add `$match` stage to filter

```
db.e2e.aggregate(
    [
        {$group   : {_id : null, maxBuild : {$max : "$build"}}},
        {$lookup  : {from : "e2e", localField : "maxBuild", foreignField : "build", as : "builds"}},
        {$unwind  : "$builds"},
        {$match   : {"builds.status" : {$ne : "NA"}}},
        {$group   : {_id : {build : "$builds.build", params : "$builds.params"}, time : {$avg : "$builds.time"}}},
        {$project : {_id : 0, build : "$_id.build", params : "$_id.params", time : "$time"}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

Comment: that worked ..thanks a lot. What if I also want to add one more filter while looking up. for example currently lookup matches maxBuild to foreignField from e2e and I want to filter this data too with some specific field like localField :"some_text_value_of_field_temp_of_e2e_collection" and foreignField : "temp".

Comment: I have updated data above, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @vgupta you  should not keep updating answered question, you should post it in a new question

Comment: You're welcome  please see the edit, ensure you've indexed build